# How can I get all html following a searched item using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to return all of the html after a search text string using BeautifulSoup in Python.  Here is my code:

```
html = '<html>table1<table><tr>text1<td>text2</td></tr></table>table2<table><tr>text3<td>text4</td></tr></table></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))
foundtext = soup.find(text='text1')
soup2 = foundtext.findAll()
```

This code is giving me error.  In soup2, I would like to have:

```
<td>text2</td></tr></table>table2<table><tr>text3<td>text4</td></tr></table></html>
```

which is all html code following the phrase 'text1'.

Comment: What do you want with BeautifulSoup(''.join(html)) ??? Why do you need this join() here???

Comment: And why do you want to apply findAl() on soup2 which is NavigableString instance and not a Tag instance....do you have any idea what you are doing?

Comment: @RestRisiko "do you have any idea what you are doing?" is a little borderline I think. I think you make some valid points regarding the OPs code and these would make a great answer, but I suspect the OP is learning, so please cut him some slack :D.

Comment: @Ninefingers: the OP is asking since days the same thing..unteachable and unwilling to read...that's the problem. The question has been ask in several variations of the last two weeks at least four or five times (not counting the questions of the OP meanwhile deleted or closed for poor quality).

Answer (score 2):

The following code will *print* out the nodes after the first occurence of text1

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = '<html>table1<table><tr>text1<td>text2</td></tr></table>table2<table><tr>text3<td>text4</td></tr></table></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

found = False
for node in soup.recursiveChildGenerator():
    if found:
        print node
    if isinstance(node, NavigableString) and node == 'text1':
        found = True


> suxmac2:tmp ajung$ bin/python out 
> <td>text2</td> text2 table2
> <table><tr>text3<td>text4</td></tr></table>
> <tr>text3<td>text4</td></tr> text3
> <td>text4</td> text4
```

Adjusting the code to your further needs is up to you...we helped you already several times. 
Once again: read the BeautifulSoup documentation - you got the link meanwhile numerous  times.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is not possible, as BeautifulSoup keeps the parsed HTML as a tree structure. What you could do is to extract all unwanted elements using http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Removing%20elements , which would return the HTML in front of your search string as well.

Apart from that, you could also use the HTML snippet from the element that you searched for. You can see in [BeautifulSoup Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#find%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs%29) that `find` returns a HTML string. Use that and simple python string-searching methods to cut away everything until the end of the found string. That will probably require more handwork and basically is like combining the answer [How can I get all html following a searched item using BeautifulSoup in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778694/how-can-i-get-all-html-following-a-searched-item-using-beautifulsoup-in-python/5778728#5778728) with BeautifulSoup's search method.